# how to passing few variables from mongodb query to jade tpl

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

```
//posts
var docs, cats;
var db = req.db;
var catcollection = db.get('catcollection');
var postcollection = db.get('postcollection');
 // find all post
     postcollection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        console.log('posts ---> '+util.inspect(docs));
      }); // end find all post
    catcollection.find({},{},function(e,catss){
        cats=catss;
      console.log('cats --> '+util.inspect(cats)); //<<<---- write objects from mongo 

     }); // end find all cats for select

res.render('newpost', {
        posts : docs, cats:cats, title: 'Add New post'});

}); **//<<<---it  didn't passing the  cats:cats and post vars to jade **
```

**jade template**

```
extends layout
  block content
   h1= title

   form#formAddPost(name="addpost",method="post",action="/addpost")

      input#inputPostTitle(type="text", placeholder="posttitle", name="posttitle")

         textarea#inputPostTitle(placeholder="postdesc", name="postdesc")

        textarea#inputPostTitle(placeholder="posttext", name="posttext")

       select#selectPostCats(placeholder="postdesc", name="posttext")
            each cat, i in cats
                     option(value="#{cat._id}") #{cat.titlecat}

         button#btnSubmit(type="submit") submit


  ul
     each post, i in posts
        li= i+" "
             a(href="/editpst/#{post._id}")=#{post.title}
```

I get this error message in jade tpl 
*Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*

but if I wrote

```
   catcollection.find({},{},function(e,catss){
      cats=catss;
        console.log('cats --> '+util.inspect(cats));
    **res.render('newpost', {
          cats:cats, title: 'Add New post'});**

   }); // end find all cats for select
```

It passing category list to jade , but i can't pass post list to jade.
How to passing few variables (posts  and  cats ) to jade tpl?

Answer (score 2):

Both of the `.find`s execute asynchronously so you don't know when (or if) either one will complete.  That is to say you need to wait until *both* of the callbacks are called before you attempt to render the template.

The simplest way in your current implementation would be to nest everything:

```
postcollection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
  // handle errors
  catcollection.find({},{},function(e,cats){
    res.render('newpost', {
      posts : docs, cats:cats, title: 'Add New post'});
    });
  }); 
});
```

However you can do these queries simultaneously because they do not depend on each other. The best way to do that is to probably use promises.

```
Promise.all([postcollection.find(), catcollection.find()])
.then(function (docs, cats) {
    res.render('newpost', {
      posts : docs, cats:cats, title: 'Add New post'});
    });
});
```

This assumes that `.find` returns a promise. It should for the current Mongo driver.